# PHP: Replace unknown characters with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I'm working with texts that, in some cases, have extra spaces within words.  For example:

> Marshawn Lynch is amazing. A M A Z I N G!

I want to collapse the "A M A Z I N G" part into one word, so that the final result looks like:

> Marshawn Lynch is amazing. AMAZING!

I'm working with PHP, and I'm trying to figure out a way to use preg_replace (maybe there's a better way of doing it?), but I can't figure out where to start.

Comment: Add the code you've tried.

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: You need to provide more samples of what you're trying to detect. For example, you probably don't want to collapse `That's a B movie.` to get `That's aB movie.` or even `That'saB movie.` So, what are you really trying to do? And *what have you tried?*

Comment: How will you differentiate between spaces within words and spaces between words? Are the words with embedded spaces always upper case?
Is this a real world problem or an exercise?

Comment: [`(?<=[A-Z])(\s)(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/nY1aW2/1)

Answer (score 0):

This one looks for whitespaces between two **UPPERCASE** letters and replaces all occurences:

```
$string = "Marshawn Lynch is amazing. A M A Z I N G!";
$regex = "~(?<=[A-Z])\s(?=[A-Z])~";
$string = preg_replace($regex, "", $string);
echo $string;
// output: Marshawn Lynch is amazing. AMAZING!
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Y8QWsM).